# OAuthAccessTokenException-The access_token provided is invalid

Tags: python, api, oauth, instagram

I am trying to follow along with the Python-Instagram simple example on their [readme](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram):

`api = InstagramAPI(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
popular_media = api.media_popular(count=20)
for media in popular_media:
    print media.images['standard_resolution'].url`

However, every time I try with my own client_id and client_secret I get the following error and have been unable to figure out how to solve it:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/Instagram API/InstaApiTest.py", line 10, in <module>
    popular_media = api.media_popular(count=20)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 197, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 189, in execute
    content, next = self._do_api_request(url, method, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 163, in _do_api_request
    raise InstagramAPIError(status_code, content_obj['meta']['error_type'], content_obj['meta']['error_message'])
instagram.bind.InstagramAPIError: (400) OAuthAccessTokenException-The access_token provided is invalid.`

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to the tutorial being out of date.  Note that the [README file](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram/blob/master/README.md) in the tutorial repo (which hasn't been updated in years) warns:

> This project is not actively maintained. Proceed at your own risk!

Instagram doesn't even list `media/popular/` on their [media endpoints official documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/) anymore.  Even when it was a thing, there's [some indication](https://www.hitchhq.com/instagram/activities/5759814d8e2e411000b8e58a) that you needed an actual access token, even a couple of years back, contrary to what the tutorial you're following states.

**TL;DR** - Look for a different tutorial, this endpoint is either changed or requires full authentication.